# Problem with Radial Array (Object offset about an Empty) on Blender 3.1.2

Tags: modifiers, edit-mode, object-mode

I'm a fledging in Blender and I've been monkeying with this amazing software for a few days. When I came around to Modifier -> Array, I got stuck into the option Object offset. With a bunch of tips I learned from Google and Youtube, in order to make a radial array for a selected object, we need to go through these following basic steps below:

1. Add an Empty Plain Axes system
2. Move the Cursor to World Origin
3. Move the center of the selected object to Cursor
4. Turn off Relative and Constant Offset
5. Turn on Object Offset and choose the Empty
6. Add more selected object number
7. Rotate the Empty Plain Axes system about Z axis.

It didn’t work eventually and resulted in a crazy outcome.

I also turned my problem over to a video and it shows you three situations with the cube: the first is the standard, the second is the 45-degee-rotated, and the third is the resized. It, the radial array, only worked for the standard cube. The video is attached below for my explanation and your consideration.

I thought the answer is somewhere in the Preference of the Edit or otherwise, “I have no idea!” though. So, is there anyone here giving me a hand, my predecessors?

Thank you so much,

[enter link description here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cfwWN6VaduA)

Comment: to add to Agnivesh's answer, instead of doing the transformation of your object in Object mode, do it in Edit mode, so that you won't need to apply the scale or rotation

Comment: Like @moonboots said, you wouldn't have the problem if you manipulated the cube in _Edit Mode_. The thing is, the _Object Offset_ is not moving the instances per each step by the value applied on the empty, but by the difference between the empty and the original object. So even if you don't do anything with the empty, if you rotate the object by e.g. 15° on the X axis, then the cube instances will be rotated 15° on X per each step around the origin point. If you then rotate the empty on the Z, both rotations will be applied for each step of the instances.

Comment: And this applies to all transformations. It's not just how the empty is transformed, it's the difference between the objects. Are the origins of the cube and the empty 1 meter apart on the X axis (no matter if the origins are at the world center or anywhere else)? Then each instance will be 1 meter on X away from the previous instance. Is there a Z angle difference of 10°? Then each instance is rotated 10° more on Z. Is the cube scaled to 0.5 on Y and the empty has a scale of 1? Then each instance will be twice as wide in Y direction then the previous instance.

Comment: Oh by the way: one last thing, if you manipulate the cube in _Edit Mode_, another advantage aside from not having to apply transformations would be that the origin stays where it is and you don't have to move the origin to the 3D cursor afterwards.

Comment: Also if you move the object in Edit mode the origin will stay where it is, no need to move it afterwards

Comment: Thank you, my predecessors! All of your answers are very helpful. Because I'm a newbie, I switched back and forth between Edit Mode and Object Mode to modify the model in a haphazard way when following the tutorial video, which led to that crazy outcome consequentially. I also made another video according to all your answers with 2 situations: one is modifying in Object Mode and the other is modifying in both Object Mode and Edit Mode haphazardly (this is my case). And applying Rotation & Scale solveed the problem at the end.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Possible reason is you haven't applied transformations to the object before using the modifiers, so before using the array modifier press, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> +  <kbd>A</kbd> and apply Rotation and Scale

[image: Apply Rotation & Scale]

Comment: Your solution is the key. Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for all your answers. The best solution is to apply the transformations before using modifiers. And the other important thing is remembering to try manipulating the object as much in the Edit Mode as possible.

See the video attached below for more clarification.

[Enter link here to see the solution video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BQGw1LKHwlg)